# Convert Knockout object with Observables to regular objects

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an object like below.

```
var order = function (data) {
    this.OrderId = data.Id;
    this.CustomerName = ko.observable(data.CustomerName);
    this.CustomerAddress = ko.observable(data.CustomerAddress);
    this.CustomerPhone = ko.observable(data.CustomerPhone);
    this.TotalPrice = ko.observable(data.TotalPrice);
    this.Cancelled = ko.observable(data.Cancelled);
    this.Pizzas = ko.observableArray();
};
```

In my VM:

```
var currentOrder = new model.Order({});
```

When this object gets modified from the UI, everything works fine. My problem comes in when I want to pass this object to my data layer to get saved. It comes in like:

[image: Chrome console.log output]

Obviously, I can't pass this to my data layer. Is there an easy way to strip this complex object of all the knockout stuff without manually writing a big mapper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
ko.toJS(currentOrder);
```

or

```
ko.toJSON(currentOrder);
```

Knockout docs [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).